# Does Bitcoin RPC API have a realtime websocket?

Tags: bitcoin-core, api, json-rpc

I am trying to create some app based on RPC API call from bitcoin core.

I want to make my btc core daemon send a notification whenever a new transaction is observed. Does BTC core RPC API have a websocket interface to make a call when new transaction happens ?

Comment: Do you want the call happen for every transaction on the network or just transactions in your wallet?

Comment: just on my wallet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you only care about transactions involving your wallet, you can specify the `walletnotify` option in your bitcoin.conf or your bitcoind start command.

Since `walletnotify` allows you to execute an arbitrary command with the new tx info, it's fairly easy to make it call a webhook on your application, or invoke your application via the command line, or pass the information on in any number of other ways.